# Dropwizard JDBI - Connection already closed

Tags: dropwizard, jdbi

While running a CRON JOB, getting an exception saying **Connection is already Closed**.
Application is running on dropwizard and following is the database configuration

```
    minSize: 8
    maxSize: 32
    checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
    maxConnectionAge: 60 minutes
    evictionInterval: 10s
    removeAbandoned: false
    checkConnectionOnBorrow: true
    minIdleTime: 10s
```

Please help fixing the issue.

Comment: This is almost certainly coming from your connection pool settings. Try enabling checkConnectionWhileIdle or removeAbandoned.

Comment: If I enable removeAbandoned, it says closed ResultSet.
If I enable checkConnectionWhileIdle, it still says connection is already closed.

Comment: Your eviction intervals and/or idle times may be too aggressive

Comment: i have changes those to 10 minutes. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this answer for anyone who happens to have the same issue I did:

I was trying to access a ResultIterable outside of the handle-callback. Parsing my ResultIterable inside the callback resolved this error for me.